# List all permutations & combinations in Integer Arraylist recursively

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I have a method `perm1` that prints all permutations/combinations of characters in a string

```
// print permutation / combination of the characters of the string s (in order)
public  static void perm1(String s) { perm1("", s); }
private static void perm1(String prefix, String s) {
    int N = s.length();
    if (N == 0) System.out.println(prefix); 
    else {
        System.out.println(prefix);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
           perm1(prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, N));
    }
}
```

`perm1` works OK and produces the desired output.

I am trying to create a similar method `perm2` that works on an arraylist of Integers

```
public static void perm2(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
    ArrayList<Integer> sub = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    perm2(sub, a);
}
public static void perm2(ArrayList<Integer> sub, ArrayList<Integer> a){
    int L = a.size();
    if (L==0) System.out.println(sub);
    else {
        System.out.println(sub);
        for (int i = 0; i < L; i++){
            sub.add(a.get(i));
            a.remove(i);
            perm2(sub, a);
            L = a.size(); // to avoid Index out of bounds exception
        }           
    }
}
```

This does not generate all the permutations and combinations as I am hoping. Using an arraylist [1, 2, 3], it only prints the following:

```
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Can anyone please tell me how to modify perm2 so that it will print the other expected values like [2] [3] [2, 3] [3, 2] [2, 3, 1] [2, 1, 3] etc...

Comment: What is the full desired output?

Comment: if the arraylist is {1,2,3}, the expected output is {}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1} - the order does not matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The need for `L=a.size()` should've been a hint. `sub` and `a` values should be preserved (their positions and values) for a proper functioning.

Below code creates a new copy of the array lists and operates on them:

```
public static void perm2(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
        ArrayList<Integer> sub = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        perm2(sub, a);
    }

 public static void perm2(ArrayList<Integer> sub, ArrayList<Integer> a) {
     int L = a.size();
     if (L == 0) System.out.println(sub);
     else {
         System.out.println(sub);
         for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
             ArrayList<Integer> ab = new ArrayList<Integer>(sub);
             ab.add(a.get(i));
             ArrayList<Integer> bc = new ArrayList<Integer>(a);
             bc.remove(i);
             perm2(ab, bc);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: This seems to be moving in the right direction, but it is giving repeated elements [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 1, 3]. I needed to uncomment the second System.out.println(sub) in order to returning the smaller combinations like [1] [2] [3] [1, 2] [1,3] etc.

Comment: Thanks boxed__l - this solution works well for my needs ! It is for an exercise in recursion, so it does not matter that it is expensive ...

Answer (score 3):

I highly suggestion looking into Google's Guava package:

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html

This package has the very useful method "permutations(Collection elements)"

This package also contains the method "powerSet(Set set)" in the "Sets" class.  http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html

Nesting calls to powerSet(Set) and permutations(Collection) should make things pretty easy.

Comment: I think this should be a comment as its a suggestion to a software.